# Insert (INSERT INTO) a table into another table containing a sequence (SERIAL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a main table created as:

```
    CREATE TABLE main_data
    (
      id SERIAL NOT NULL,
      name character varying(249),
      telephone character varying(248)
    )
```

While I get a new table `backup_date` containing only name and telephone which I restore and add to my database.

Now I want to add the `backup_date` to the `main_data` so that when the `backup_date` table is added to the `main_table` it automatically continues the sequence of `id`. How can I do that?

**NOTE** After a lot of searching I can only got this solution;

`INSERT INTO users (name, age, id) VALUES ('Mozart', 20, DEFAULT);`

as I have huge amount of data in the `backup_date` I cannot use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, all you need is:

```
insert into main_data (name,telephone) select name,telephone from backup_date
```

Comment: Does SERIAL mean autoincrement id?

Comment: serial is a shortcut for create sequence, assign it to a table set default value for a field as `nextval` - so yes, very close I think

Comment: Thanks for the info. Seems to be handy!

Comment: Darn, I added a id column to the `backup_date` as NULL and then tried to insert all three columns, no wonder I led myself down a rabbit hole, while the answer was so simple and uncomplicated. Thanks @VaoTsun

Answer (score -1):

**Hi Hassan -**

If your ID column is auto increment then just your code will be -

```
insert into main_data (name,telephone) select name,telephone from backup_date where [your condition]
```

And if your ID column is not auto increment then first set it auto increment and then execute above query. Thanks :)